# running node.js forever on shared hosting(Bluehost)

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, shared-hosting, bluehost

I'm running node.js app on Bluehost server.. I tried using forever and nohup, but when I close the ssh connection or my computer sleeps, the server gives me 503 error.

I added these lines to my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:58500/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:58500/$1 [P,L]
```

I don't know if I should write a script to keep the server alive or not

Comment: add any script to startup at boot, via @reboot cron job, upstart/systemd etc its closing because your terminal session closes. btw it has nothing to do with htaccess

Comment: @LawrenceCherone where should I place this script? I'm new to backend so I don't get it